# Redmine and Facebook Connect

Tags: facebook, redmine, redmine-plugins

I'm looking for this for the whole day today without results. Does anyone know to to use facebook-connect as an authentication mechanism in Redmine? Is there any working plugin for that? Or other solution?

Comment: Were you able to figure that out? I am also searching for facebook connect for redmine

Answer (score 1):

I think this plugin can help you to solve the problem
https://github.com/buoyant/redmine_tweetbook